# Request body is declared but the log shows it is undefined both on client-side and server-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

On client side I'm doing a fetchAPI like below, at which I clearly declare `req.body`, however the `req.body` is logged as `undefined` and I cannot figure out why:

```
let req=new Request('/register',{
    method:'POST',
    body:JSON.stringify({
        name:'name',
        email:'email'
    }),
    headers:new Headers({
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }),
})

console.log(req.body)
//logs "undefined" on browser console: I wonder why???

fetch(req).then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>{
    console.log(data)
})
```

Also on server-side the `req.body` is logged as undefined:

```
server.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
    // logs "undefined" on Linux console, again I'm not quite sure why!!!
})
```

---

### UPDATE

As mentioned on the accepted answer, the `body-parser` middleware was missing, I added the following lines of code to server-side code:

```
bodyParser=require('body-parser')

server.use(bodyParser.json())
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

server.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
    //Now Linux console logs: "{ name: 'name', email: 'email' }"
    //Therefore server receives browser request correctly

    res.json({
        msg:'Server received your request'
    })
})
```

Therefore the problem is solved now, also the web-browser console logs the server response correctly:

```
let req=new Request('/register',{
    method:'POST',
    body:JSON.stringify({
        name:'name',
        email:'email'
    }),
    headers:new Headers({
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }),

})

console.log(req.body)
// Browser console still logs "undefined" here

fetch(req).then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>{
    console.log(data)
    //Browser console logs here: "Object {msg: "Server received your request"}"
    //Therefore browser receives server response correctly
})
```

The only unclear thing which remains is that web-browser is still logging `req.body` as `undefined`. Based on @jfriend00 comment, I think that's because:

> In many frameworks, the body is available in a stream, but has not yet been read when the request starts so there's nothing in req.body yet.

Comment: What is your server framework?  In many frameworks, the body is available in a stream, but has not yet been read when the request starts so there's nothing in `req.body` yet.  You could either read it yourself in your request handler or you can use middleware that will read and parse it for you into `req.body`.

Comment: Then Trieu's answer is one way to do it.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, actually, his answer worked and now server-side logs the `req.body` as `{ name: 'name', email: 'email' }`, but still the web-browser console logs `undefinded`

Comment: When you send a response from the client, it does not go in `req.body`.  Not sure why you thought it would.  It is sent as a stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess on the server-side, you are using Expressjs framework, right?

If so, you need to use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) module to parse the json from request payload.

The code may look like:

```
const server = require('express')();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

server.use(bodyParser.json());

// Your codes here
server.post()....
```